# How to run junit tests on a method that returns void?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

*I cannot change the signature of the method that needs to be tested*. The test code looks like below

```
Parser test = new Parser(props);
ArrayList<HDocument> list = new ArrayList<HDocument>();

test.parse("/users/mac/test.xml", list);
System.out.println("Size of list: "+list.size());
assertEquals(5, list.size());
```

`parse` method signature is as below

```
public void parse(String filename, Collection<HDocument> docs)
```

The parse method runs fine, but when I run the tester, the list size is always 0. I cannot change the parse method signature. How should I do it?

Here is the Parser class,

```
class Parser{
private Collection<HDocument> docs;
     public void parse(String filename, Collection<HDocument> docs) {
        docs = new ArrayList<HDocument>();
        Collection<HDocument> docsFromXml = new ArrayList<HDocument>();

            Handler hl = new Handler();
            try {
                docsFromXml = hl.getDocs(filename);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            docs = docsFromXml;
            System.out.println("Size:"
                    + docs.size()); // This prints the size correctly

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a print statement inside parse method and I get the list size as 5 getting printed from the method, but the print statement here is reporting it as 0.

Comment: Then you should check the state of your object...

Comment: Do you care about the size of list ? or the contents of the list. if you want the size. return docsFromXml.size()  or if you want the contents return the collection itself.

Comment: No, your parse(...) is wrong. The test seems to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `parse` is supposed to add the results into the `docs` collection, and the size of `docs` is zero after you run the `parse` method, then your test is telling you that `parse` is broken, or you're calling it wrong.  That's what tests are *supposed* to do: tell you that something isn't working.

In short: you're testing `parse` correctly, and your test is correctly telling you something else is broken.  Your test is fine; it's `parse` that must be wrong somehow.  (Perhaps the question you should be asking StackOverflow is how to fix your `parse` method.)

Comment: I have added the code for the method. What needs to be changed so that the list retains after the function call in the tester class.

Comment: Your problem is that `docs = docsFromXml` doesn't actually change `list` in the test; it only changes it within the `parse` method.  You mustn't do `docs = new ArrayList<HDocument>` -- or `docs =` anything -- within `parse`; instead, you must leave `docs` as it is, and call `docs.addAll(docsFromXml)` or something that changes the _contents_ of `docs`, not the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the parse-method itself.

```
public void parse(String filename, Collection<HDocument> docs) {
    docs = new ArrayList<HDocument>(); /* First problem here: The method should add values to the parameter not to a new List-Instance */
    [...]
    docs = docsFromXml; // second error here. you overwrite the list again.
```

Should be something like:

```
public void parse(String filename, Collection<HDocument> docs) {
        if(docs==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("no list for adding values specified");
        if(filename==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("no filename specified");
        Handler hl = new Handler();
        try {
            docs.addAll(hl.getDocs(filename));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeEception(e); // never sink exception without proper handling
        }

    }
}
```